# How does Style.map(background = ['state', 'any_color']) affect ttk.Button?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

### Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

win = tk.Tk()

style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('default')
style.configure('styled.TButton', foreground = 'blue', background = 'yellow')
style.map('styled.TButton', foreground = [('pressed', 'red')], background = [('disabled','yellow')]) 

btn = ttk.Button(win, text = 'Styled Button', style = 'styled.TButton')
btn.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

### Output:

[image: output1]

### Compare:

If we modify as follows,

```
style.map('styled.TButton', foreground = [('pressed','red')], background = [('active','yellow')])
```

the output remains the same.

### Question:

How are both different?

Answer (score 2):

The difference between them is that `disabled` state color used when your button is disabled and `active` state color when it is enabled. You can simply disable your buttons via changing it's state like this:

```py
btn['state'] = 'disabled'
```

And I changed you code a bit so you can see the difference between them:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

win = tk.Tk()

style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('default')
style.configure('styled.TButton', foreground = 'blue', background = 'yellow')
style.map('styled.TButton', foreground = [('pressed', 'red')], background = [('active','yellow'), ('disabled','blue')])

btn = ttk.Button(win, text = 'Styled Button', style = 'styled.TButton')
btn.pack()
btn['state'] = 'disabled'

win.mainloop()
```

So there if your button disabled it will be blue but if it is enabled it will be yellow.

Comment: In my code, is `btn` in `active` or `disabled` state?

Comment: in ```active```

Comment: Then why does `style.map(background = [('disabled','yellow')])` affect the code? If you delete that option for `style.map()`, `btn` will behave differently. That is, `style.map('styled.TButton', foreground = [('pressed','red')])`

Comment: Good question. I honestly don't know, but there are two assumptions. First one - it is possible that the Tk itself turns off the button for a short time after pressing it and therefore its color changes. Second one - the Tk can take the color you specified and apply it to all options, because you did not specify colors for the rest of the options.